# onActivityResult return data from fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

I Have an activity A that opens an activity B using `startActivityForResult`.

Now in activity B it's an activity fragment holder as well it contains an `ActionBar` with menu items.

Now whenever I press action bar button in activity B it should return data from selected fragment of an activity B not to its holder instead it should return data to activity A because it's the one who did the launch.

So it's basically passing data fragment (inside activity B) to activity B then to Activity A.

I am trying hopelessly to find a way to solve it. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: But.. if I understood.. you want to return data from Fragment inside activity B to Activity A, right?

Comment: no it's a return data from a fragment inside an activity B to Activity A it's different

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley yes is it possible ?

Comment: @mba3gar ok, but you can do it in another way: from Fragment you set the data to ActivityB, then you return it from B to A.. isn't easier?

Comment: Fragment won't return data back to activity A because it is inside activity B and it's not supposed to return anything to A anyway. Your activity B has to return something to activity A. So when your fragment pass something to 'B' just pass it forward to 'A' and finish 'B'.

Comment: @Ranjan can you show me please an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer** there are many ways, this is the one I prefer, not the best ever and not the perfect one, I just like this.

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to pass the data from Fragment inside B to ActivityB, then from ActivityB to ActivityA.

**Step 1** to pass data from Fragment to container activity you have many ways; the one I usually use is to use an Interface:

**Create interface for ActivityB**

```
public interface IActivityB {
    void setDataAAndFinish(whateverType data);
}
```

**Implement interface in your activityB**

```
public class InterventoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IInterventoActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private Bundle dataA = null;
    @Override
    public void setDataAAndFinish(whateverType data) {
        dataA = data;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("data", data)
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
        finish();
    }
}
```

**Set activityA to request and accept return from ActivityB**

**first, start activityB for result and not normally**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

**Then read result**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             whateverType data = data.getStringExtra("data");
         }     
    }
}
```

**Now from fragment**

```
((IActivityB)getActivity()).setDataAAndFinish(myDatas);
```

Comment: in activity B fragment container i created an interface called height as below
`interface Height {
    void sendHeight(int data);
}`

and inside a fragment B i create a new instance of this activity 
`ActivityB b = new ActivityB(); then i tried to call b.sendHeight(2);`
with no success

Comment: @mba3gar I forgot the line about the call for the method sorry, I just added it. Anyway consider using interfaces a lot, they are really useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a function in your `ActivityB` like the following.

```
public void sendDataBackToActivityA(String dataToBePassedToActivityA) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("data", dataToBePassedToActivityA);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Now from the `Fragment` that you launched from `ActivityB`, just call the method on some action in your `Fragment` that was launched from `ActivityB`. So the pseudo implementation of the process in your `Fragment` should look like the following. Declare this function in your `Fragment` and invoke the function on some action in your `Fragment`.

```
public void sendDataToActivityAFromFragment(String dataToBePassed) {
    ((ActivityB)getActivity()).sendDataBackToActivityA(dataToBePassed);
}
```

This will serve your purpose I hope.

Comment: Great to know that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare static variables in your A activity and set it from the B activity

Or you can make static class and set variables values from B Activity and get it in A activity

Or you can send the menu value from Activity B to A while you exit Activity B and start activity A by using bundle

Comment: Using static variable can cause memory leaks.Its not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

this is how you set the data to be passed to activity A  in activity B

```
  val resultIntent = Intent()
        resultIntent.putExtra(DATA, "closed")
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent)
        finish()
```

this is how you get data in activity A

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (requestCode == FILE_UPLOAD_CODE) {
                when (resultCode) {
                    Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                                      // data here is obtained data of the method paramater
                     }}}}
```

Comment: can't declare intent inside Fragment

Comment: yes but you can pass your data to activity through interface and then the activity run the intent

Comment: fragment inside activity B , to activity B than to Activity A is there any possible way to do it ?

Comment: yes many , simplest one is using interface/listener pattern , then there is observable pattern and then there is MVVM model to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity A.Move from activity A to b like this:-

```
int YOUR_CODE=101;  // it can be whatever you like
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), B.class);                   
startActivityForResult(i,YOUR_CODE);
```

In your Activity B in its fragment

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("NAME OF THE PARAMETER", valueOfParameter);
...
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

And in your **Activity A's onActivityResult()** function do this:-

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

         if (resultCode==YOUR_CODE)
         {
           String value = (String) data.getExtras().getString("NAME OF THE PARAMETER");  //get Data here

         }

     }

    }
```

Comment: how you get the data from fragment inside activity B ?

Comment: Updated my post ,kindly check second code in which data is passed throud resultIntent.putExtra() fuction.You need to access action bar button clickLister inside fragment.

Comment: am not able to send data from fragment to another activity how you create an intent inside a fragment of an activity B ?

Comment: Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("NAME OF THE PARAMETER", valueOfParameter);
...
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();

Answer (score 0):

```
In kotlin: - 
In class A
startActivityForResult(Intent(context, B::class.java), 143)

  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == 143) {
            if (data!!.extras.get("check").equals("0")) {
                childpager.currentItem = 0
            }
        }
    }

In Class B
 val intent = Intent()
 intent.putExtra("check", "0")
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code: What does it do, how does it work, how does it solve OPs problem, and what makes it different from the existing answers. Code only answers can lead to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), and you risk getting downvotes.